# Listview Button Selected values not showing on repeat

Tags: visualforce

Hello i have this visualforce page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" recordSetVar="opportunities" cache="true"  >
    <apex:pageBlock title="Selected Opportunities" id="muselectedlist">
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!selected}" var="opp" id="mutab">
            <apex:column value="{!opp.name}" id="oppname"/>
            <apex:column value="{!opp.stagename}" id="oppstage"/>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

I use it in a custom button list view, i select 1 or more record and click the button, but none of the records are displayed in my page. Anyone know why?

Comment: Can you also provide the configuration of the list button?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is happening because of the configuration of the custom list button. Your VF markup is perfect and works fine as tested with this configuration:

---

[image: Button Configuration]

---

**Added the button to the Opportunity Search Layout:**

---

[image: Search Layout]

---

**Select the desired records and click the custom button to display your VF page:**

---

[image: VF Page]