# how to get the related records of the child (custom object) from parent record (Quote Object)

Tags: visualforce, custom-object, quote

I have a custom object as "Compitetor" ,which has a lookup relation to "QUOTE " object.So created a "list button "for the custom object ,using the standard controller.

1)Now im unable to get the related records to "edit" when i click on the "list button".

2)It does not displays the column names in the VF Page.PFA ScreenShot

Any suggestion Plz.

```
<apex:page StandardController="Compitetor__c" sidebar="false" recordSetVar="Competitors">
 <apex:form >
  <apex:sectionHeader title="Edit for Competitor"/>
  <apex:pageBlock title="Quote Update" >
   <apex:pageBlockButtons >
    <apex:commandButton action="{!SAVE}" value="SAVE"/>
    <apex:commandButton action="{!CANCEL}" value="CANCEL"/>
   </apex:pageBlockButtons>
   <apex:pageBlockSection >
    <apex:inputField value="{!Compitetor__c.CustomQuote__c}"/>
   </apex:pageBlockSection>
   <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Selected}" var="com">
    <apex:column value="{!com.Name}"/>
    <apex:column value="{!com.Product_Series__c}" />
    <apex:column value="{!com.Part_Number__c}"/>
    <apex:column value="{!com.Price_Offered__c}"/>
    <apex:column value="{!com.Volume__c}"/>
    <apex:column value="{!com.Date_Price_is_valid__c}"/>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Comment: your visualforce code is unreadable. Better copy paste it into your question in txt.

Comment: @guy:i have copied my code and pasted in question but still invisible.

Comment: @nikkey - I do not see a list button in your code OR the display of the lookup object....

Comment: It might be the list button config. Check this answer http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5937/listview-button-selected-values-not-showing-on-repeat